# Python fabric put statistics

Tags: python, fabric

When I put a file on a remote server (using `put()`), is there anyway I can see the upload information or statistics printed to the stdout file descriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such way according to the [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put). You could however try the [project tools](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/contrib/project.html).

There's also the option to play with fabric's `local` function, but of course breaks the whole host concept.

There's also no way to make fabric more verbose than the default (except for debugging). This makes sense because fabric doesn't really work with terminal escape keys to delete lines again. Displaying statistics would print way to many lines. This would actually be a nice feature - detecting line deletions within fabric and applying them (just throwing the idea out for a potential pull request).